# VB6 can't load DLL COM registered in Win10

Tags: vb6

In Win7, I have an application VB6 that references `C:\Windows\SystemWOW64\FM20.dll`. This dll is put into `SysWOW64` by Office 2010 32 bit. This is a COM dll.

After upgrade to Win10, my application show message error that it can't find FM20.

In Win10, the dll is already registrered because I can find the class in `regedit`

They have almost same registry but there area light difference

In Win7 (worked) : [image: In Win 7]

In Win10 (not work) : [image: In Win 10]

Anyone has an idea how to make the application work please ? We don't want to move FM20.dll to WOW64 and regsvr32 it for some reason

Comment: The DLL does not necessarily have to be in `SystemWOW64`, it just has to be at the location the registry says. Move it wherever you want and call `regsvr32` on it. (Also, don't post screenshots from your registry. Export the relevant keys, post the text.)

Comment: You [already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60211816/11683) that question, there was no need to delete and repost it. The first comment under it is correct.

Comment: Also, `vb6-migration` is not an applicable tag for this question. That tag is for language migration from vb6 to a different language (usually .net based).

Comment: @GSerg I thought I recognized this too.

Comment: Did you try to unregister and re-register it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the path is stored under the key **Win64**, my guess is that it is a 64-bit component. If that is correct, then there is no way that you will be able to load it using VB6, which a 32-bit application.

Do you have a 32-bit or a 64-bit version of Microsoft office?

Actually, I am not familiar with 64-bit COM, but I am certain that the key must be **Win32** for a 32-bit component.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully call a 64 bit COM dll from VB6 app using DLLSurrogates. Please see for this for more help. https://www.mobilize.net/blog/call-64-bits-code-from-a-32bit-vb6-app